# Bar-charts plot order depending on values (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Considering two series of values `rr1` and `rr2`:

```
rr1 <- c(-1, -0.6, 1.7, 6.3, 9, 10, 8.8, 6.2, 4.5, 4, 3.4)
rr2 <- c(-2.3, -1.8, -4, -5.7, -7.2, -5.6, -2.3, 0.2, -0.3, -1.4, -1.3)
```

Figure 1:
[image]

`rr1` is mainly positive (except for x=-5 and x=-4) while `rr2` is negative (except for x=2).

Using `ggplot2` to group `rr1` and `rr2` in the same bar-chart (Figure 2):

```
dat <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("rr1", "rr2"), each=11),
  x = rep(-5:5, 2),
  y = c(rr1, rr2)
)
ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=-5:5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-10,10,2.5), limits=c(-10,10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14), axis.text.y=element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

Figure 2:
[image]

Is there a way for `rr1` to be plotted over `rr2` when x is equal to -5 and -4?

Comment: It lookw like a bug to me. Why, for example, when x == 2, both `rr1` and `rr2` were plotted on the positive scale? It seems not to work on negative scales. You should file a bug and then it wait until it will work as supposed to

Comment: @DavidArenburg Because `rr1` and `rr2` are both positives when x=2 (6.2 and 0.2, respectively).

Comment: This is my point exactly, and it still works (they are not being overlaid by each other). While in x == -5 they are both negative and it doesn't work (being overlaid by each other). This is inconsistent. Definitely a bug

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't know what the default behavior is supposed to be, but I bet `rr1` is plotted below `rr2`, due to the plot order. Because if you reverse the order of `rr1` and `rr2` in `dat`, `rr2` is below `rr1` for x=2.

Comment: But this is a stacked bar plot. They are not supposed to be plotted below each other. When, they are both positive, are they being plotted below each other? No. This is only happens when they are both negatives

Comment: @DavidArenburg It is not a stacked bar plot.

Comment: Hmm.. I didn't notice that. But it still works only for positive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `rr2` values prints over `rr1`, so there is manual solution - first print all positive rr1 then all negative rr2, negative rr1 and positive rr2.

```
rr1 <- c(-1, -0.6, 1.7, 6.3, 9, 10, 8.8, 6.2, 4.5, 4, 3.4)
rr2 <- c(-2.3, -1.8, -4, -5.7, -7.2, -5.6, -2.3, 0.2, -0.3, -1.4, -1.3)

dat <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("rr1", "rr2"), each=11),
  x = rep(-5:5, 2),
  y = c(rr1, rr2)
)

positive_rr1 <- subset(dat,group=="rr1" & y >=0)
negative_rr1 <- subset(dat,group=="rr1" & y <0)
positive_rr2 <- subset(dat,group=="rr2" & y >=0)
negative_rr2 <- subset(dat,group=="rr2" & y <0)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(data=positive_rr1,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(data=negative_rr2,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(data=negative_rr1,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(data=positive_rr2,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=-5:5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-10,10,2.5), limits=c(-10,10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14), axis.text.y=element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

[image]

The chart above is not stacked chart, because rr1 is printed over rr2, to get stacked chart we can modify `dat`

```
for(i in -5:5){
  if(dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr1","y"] < 0 & dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr2","y"] < 0){
    dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr2","y"] <- dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr2","y"]+
      dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr1","y"]
  }
  if(dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr1","y"] > 0 & dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr2","y"] > 0){
    dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr1","y"] <- dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr2","y"]+
      dat[dat$x==i & dat$group=="rr1","y"]
  }
}

positive_rr1 <- subset(dat,group=="rr1" & y >=0)
negative_rr1 <- subset(dat,group=="rr1" & y <0)
positive_rr2 <- subset(dat,group=="rr2" & y >=0)
negative_rr2 <- subset(dat,group=="rr2" & y <0)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(data=positive_rr1,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(data=negative_rr2,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(data=negative_rr1,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  geom_bar(data=positive_rr2,stat="identity", position="identity", width=0.25) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=-5:5) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(-10,10,2.5), limits=c(-10,10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=14), axis.text.y=element_text(size=14), legend.text=element_text(size=14))
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping `ggplot2` to be able to automatically manage this case. It seems no.

Comment: There is no reason what soever that these values will be printed one over each other, as we dealing with stacked plot here. Not to mention that this works for positive values when x == 2

Comment: So, in that case, I definitively have to do as @Pigeon suggested.

Comment: @Pascal, you should first file a bug report so it will be fixed in the near future and will allow you to do this normal way. For now, Pigeons suggestions seems to be  good alternative

Comment: Added stacked chart, cause first in first graph values are printed on top (for example when x is -5 )

Comment: @Pigeon, it is not a stacked barchart.